# Error while building mupdf 1.1 on mac

Tags: android, android-ndk, mupdf

am using latest mupdf-1.1-source.tar.gz, mupdf-thirdparty-2012-08-14.zip and ndk-r8d, I am trying to build mupdf on mac terminal. I have already done this a few months ago on windows with older version of mupdf probably 0.9 but now on mac it is giving this error

```
ndk-build
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
Compile thumb  : mupdf <= mupdf.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_context.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_error.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_geometry.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_getopt.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_hash.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_memory.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_string.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= base_time.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= crypt_aes.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= crypt_arc4.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= crypt_md5.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= crypt_sha2.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= dev_bbox.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= dev_list.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= dev_null.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= dev_text.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= dev_trace.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= doc_document.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= doc_link.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= doc_outline.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= filt_basic.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= filt_dctd.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= filt_faxd.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= filt_flate.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= filt_jbig2d.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= filt_lzwd.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= filt_predict.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= image_jpx.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= image_jpeg.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= image_png.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= image_tiff.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= res_colorspace.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= res_font.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= res_path.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= res_pixmap.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= res_shade.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= res_store.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= res_text.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= stm_buffer.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= stm_open.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= stm_read.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= draw_affine.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= draw_blend.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= draw_device.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= draw_edge.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= draw_glyph.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= draw_mesh.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= draw_paint.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= draw_path.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= draw_simple_scale.c
/var/folders/13/t2hb6n5964qf3vcy1_w1gyg00000gn/T//ccpBK4tU.s: Assembler messages:
/var/folders/13/t2hb6n5964qf3vcy1_w1gyg00000gn/T//ccpBK4tU.s:2384: Error: lo register required -- `str fp,[sp,#-4]!'
/var/folders/13/t2hb6n5964qf3vcy1_w1gyg00000gn/T//ccpBK4tU.s:2390: Error: lo register required -- `add fp,sp,#0'
```

and this error `lo register required` continues for good 30-40 lines.

I have searched all over but wasn't able to find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MuPdf Works on mupdf-1.1,android-ndk-r8b (Take care do not download android-ndk-r8d),cygwin-2.774

When Download cygwin download libraries for make,gcc commands and other required libraries..!

Then if u get any prob...i will try to solve..!

Comment: I just tried it yesterday, was working on some other project. It had other problems which I solved but r8b solved my main problem.

Comment: @Naveen-i have passed through same problem.That's why when i read ur question on that day i replied immediately.....i m happy that you have solved it..have agood day...!