# Android MuPDF Reader Set Up

Tags: android, android-ndk, mupdf

I need to display a PDF document inside a Fragment, after some online research, i came across MuPDF reader which is most prefered and open source reader, I followed all the steps in this link  http://mupdf.blogspot.in/. When i try to compile this MuPDF library through Cyqwin with the following command as per the above blog

```
**Open Cygwin console,(just double click cygwin installation short-cut) and type following command and enter.
cd /cygdrive/<path to mupdf sorce folder/android ex. cd /cygdrive/c/mupdf-1.0-    source/android
/cygdrive/<path to ndk installation>/ndk-build ex. /cygdrive/c/ndk/ndk-build**
```

i was getting the following error

```
**Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= draw_path.c
Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= draw_simple_scale.c
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s: Assembler messages:
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2248: Error: lo register required -- `str fp,[sp,#-4]!'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2253: Error: lo register required -- `add fp,sp,#0'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2257: Error: lo register required -- `str r0,[fp,#-16]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2258: Error: lo register required -- `str r1,[fp,#-20]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2259: Error: lo register required -- `str r2,[fp,#-24]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2260: Error: lo register required -- `str r3,[fp,#-28]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2262: Error: lo register required -- `ldr r3,[fp,#-24]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2263: Error: lo register required -- `str r3,[fp,#-8]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2267: Error: lo register required -- `ldr r3,[fp,#-16]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2269: Error: lo register required -- `str r2,[fp,#-16]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2270: Error: lo register required -- `ldr r2,[fp,#-20]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2272: Error: lo register required -- `str r1,[fp,#-20]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2276: Error: lo register required -- `ldr r3,[fp,#-8]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2278: Error: lo register required -- `str r3,[fp,#-8]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2281: Error: lo register required -- `ldr r3,[fp,#-8]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2285: Error: lo register required -- `ldr r3,[fp,#-28]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2286: Error: lo register required -- `ldr r2,[fp,#4]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2289: Error: lo register required -- `ldr r2,[fp,#-24]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:2291: Error: lo register required -- `str r3,[fp,#-8]'
...
at the end this long operation terminates with the following ...
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:4057: Error: lo register required -- `ldr r3,[fp,#-104]'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:4061: Error: lo register required -- `sub sp,fp,#8'
C:\cygwin64\tmp\ccEtywkX.s:4063: Error: lo register required -- `ldmfd sp!,{r4,fp,pc}'
/cygdrive/d/Sajay/Software/android-ndk-r9/build/core/build-binary.mk:345: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mupdfcore/__/__/draw/draw_simple_scale.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mupdfcore/__/__/draw/draw_simple_scale.o] Error 1**
```

After trying online for this issue i came across following stackoverflow question which was very similar to my issue

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050042/error-while-building-mupdf-1-1-on-mac
```

i downloaded NDK 8b and tried to compile but still i'm getting similar error in shorter form

```
Compile   : mupdf <= mupdf.c
/bin/sh: /cygdrive/d/user/Software/android-ndk-r8b-windows/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
/cygdrive/d/user/Software/android-ndk-r8b-windows/android-ndk-r8b/build/core/build-binary.mk:252: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mupdf/mupdf.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/mupdf/mupdf.o] Error 127
```

Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the error message, it looks like your toolchain doesn't include gcc ?

Comment: One of my colleagues suggests that the NDK has failed to install properly, as the gcc compiler is part of the NDK.

Comment: Thanks KenS, I got resolved, I had specified wrong tool chain version in Application.mk file which i was using for NDK 9r version.

Comment: @sajay So what did you do to resolve this? I'm using NDK-r9c and it worked on MuPDF 1.3 but when I compiled MuPDF 1.1, this error came out.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved a problem like this! I used gcc to compile a xxx.S file in my project and it threw error like this

> "../src/__sys.S:20: Error: lo register required -- 'stmdb r0!,{r4-r11}'"

and this

> "../src/__sys.S:20: Error: Thumb-2 instruction only valid in unified syntax -- `stmdb r0!,{r4}'"

---

I find a solution from this wiki
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/Thumb2PortingHowto#Types_of_Assembly_Language

and get my problem solved by **adding this line at the beginning** of my xxx.S file

```
.syntax unified
```

hope this would be useful for you!